# Unable to set the remember me cookie expiry date in laravel 4.1.28

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4, remember-me

### Background:

I was Using laravel 4.0.x , and resetting the *remember_me* cookie expiry date to 1 month (since the default is 5 years ) using this code :

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    // If the user is tryin to log_in and he wants to stay logged in, reset the remember_me cookie expiration date from 5 years to 1month
    $remember = Input::get('remember',false);
    if ($remember) {
        if ( Auth::check()){ // check if the user is logged in
            $ckname = Auth::getRecallerName(); //Get the name of the cookie, where remember me expiration time is stored
            $ckval  = Cookie::get($ckname); //Get the value of the cookie
            return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,43200)); //change the expiration time to 1 month = 43200 min
        }
    }
```

That code is from ***app\filters.php*** of course, and it was working like charm.

### The problem :

I recently updated laravel from 4.0.x to v4.1.28, and now the remember_me cookies are set to 5 years, I tried for the last hours digging in the code trying to debug but with no luck :( .
 
Notice that changing *$ckname* to another value like *"test"* in the last line of the above code works just fine, it creates a *"test"* cookie with an expiry of 1 month like I intended

```
return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make("test",$ckval,43200));
```

I don't really understand why the remember_me cookie persist to the 5 years expiry date !

Any help would be appreciated :) 
Abdou.

### Update:

The question is not why I want to change the cookie expiry date, but it's why the cookie won't get updated?! . Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide here: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade ? Also in app/config/session.php have you set the 'lifetime' property to a none zero value (like 120) ?

Comment: Yes, I followed the whole upgrade guide, & the lifetime is set to 120, frankly I don't believe it has to do with the config, since the cookie is set normally, the prob reside just in the 5 years :/

Comment: Are you using any other packages like Cartalysts Sentry with this ?

Comment: No, none but jeffrey way generator, which has nothing to do with this issue I believe.

Comment: In app/config/session.php what do you have the 'driver' property set at? Maybe add the contents of app/config/session.php to this post?

Comment: @Softinio I use the default values :
 **'driver' => 'file',
 'lifetime' => 120,
 'expire_on_close' => true,

 'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

 'connection' => null,

 'table' => 'sessions',

 'lottery' => array(2, 100),
 'cookie' => 'my_website_cookie', 
 'path' => '/',
 'domain' => null,
 'secure' => false,**

Comment: Why would you not want it to be permanent? Why would you want it to expire?

Comment: Try setting 'driver' property to 'cookie'

Answer (score 2):

This is intentional behavior with Laravel.

The remember_me settings is to "permanently" remember the User, until such time as they 'logout' of the application.

If you dig into the Auth classes - it specifically says it is a "permanent cookie".

```
public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
    {
        $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

        // If the user should be permanently "remembered" by the application we will
        // queue a permanent cookie that contains the encrypted copy of the user
        // identifier. We will then decrypt this later to retrieve the users.
        if ($remember)
        {
            $this->createRememberTokenIfDoesntExist($user);

            $this->queueRecallerCookie($user);
        }
```

There is no way to set the cookie to anything other than 'permanent' (aka 5 years).

Also - [the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users) state the remember me is forever:

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass true as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated **indefinitely** (or until they manually logout)

Edit: as you've updated your question - I looked into it more. This works for me:

```
public function login()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => ), true))
    {
        $ckname = Auth::getRecallerName();
        Cookie::queue($ckname, Cookie::get($ckname), 43200);
        return View::make('welcome');
    }
}
```

It only sets the 'remember_me' cookie to 1 month.

Comment: I'm aware that the remember me cookie is forever, & I wanted to change it to 1 month because I find 5 years to be too much, anyhow the scope of my question here is : Why my code is no longer working in v4.1.28 ! especially that setting another cookie will work